# AssertionError: null == MongoError: server instance pool was destroyed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

The subject of this question is the error message I get when I perform this `insertOne` operation in a Node/Express application.

**Code:**

```
router.post('/api/formula-list', function(req, res){
var db = req.db.collection('formulas');
var formula = data; //an array stored elsewhere in the program

db.insertOne({
  "name": req.body.name,
  "description": req.body.description,
  "formula": formula
}, function(err, r) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    assert.equal(1, r.insertedCount);
});
  data.length = 0;
});
```

I assume this means I'm having an issue with the callback in `insertOne` and a call is made to the database before it finishes.

I'm not sure how to fix this.  I'd prefer a solution that's pure javascript/mongo and doesn't require outside libraries as I'm trying to hone in on the core technology behind both Node and Mongo.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40509500/good-way-of-handling-mongoerror-server-instance-pool-was-destroyed) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39556538/server-instance-pool-was-destroyed) are very similar, but the one doesn't really have a useful answer and the other uses mongoose which I'd prefer to avoid.

**Update:**

In my app.js I initialize the driver like so:

**APP.JS**

```
// make mongodb available to the application
app.use((req, res, next) => {
mongo.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/formulas', (e, db) => {
  if (e) return next(e);
  req.db = db;
next();
});

// cleanup
  req.on('end', () => { req.db.close(); });
});
```

Comment: can you please share the connection code as well?

Comment: Are you calling db.close() anywhere below the db.insertOne?  It's mentioned in one of the questions you linked, but just double-checking.